# Android Need Help Auto Word Suggestion for Edittext and Syntax Checker

Tags: javascript, android

I'm a Beginner with App Development. Im trying to create an Offline App that have support and read JavaScript/Hmtl codes and Show the output inside a WebView. So Far i have accomplished the basic stuff which is display the users inputted JavaScript/html code inside `Edittext` and show it inside a `WebView`. My problem is I want  my Edittext to have an Autocomplete Feature, more like a code suggestion. E.g. when a user types a certain Letter inside `< >` these brackets, a dropdown suggestion is show like in Autocomplete. Note: I have already tried using autocomplete,yes it works but only once, after that it wont suggest any other words 
I know this is too much but i do hope someone can help me. Thanks in Advance and sorry for the Long Post.

Comment: One question per post please.  And bring some of your own work with you-  we don't write code for you here, we help you after you've tried to do it on your own.

Comment: im So sorry about that. i have editted my questions now Sir. as i have stated above, i have already tried the autocomplete , it works but it only limited to one selection or word.